# twice iteration over a database pdo resultset, throwing exception in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

Getting `Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException` on file

```
\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result.php:159
```

my database setting code is

```
array(
  'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'pdodriver'      => 'mysql',            
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'',
            'buffer_results' => true
        ),
        'username'       => 'root',
        'password'       => '',
        'host'           => 'localhost',
        'dbname'         => 'db_name',
  ),
)
```

result fetching code is

```
$statement  = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results    = $statement->execute();
```

and I tried `$results->buffer();` &&  `$results->rewind()`

My iterating code is like

```
foreach ( $results as $result ){    
       // code goes here ..
}
....

foreach ( $results as $result ){    
       // code goes here ..
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception you are seeing says:

> This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after
>   moving forward is not supported

Therefore the simple solution would be to store the results in an array then you can iterate over that array multiple times.

```
$records = array();

foreach ($results as $result)
{
    $records[] = $result;
}
```

Comment: After having this same issue and using the same solution as mentioned in this answer, I found the [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) php function that achieves the same results. Definitely beats writing 5 lines of boilerplate every time you need this kind of resultset.

Answer (score 9):

This is because the PDO resultset is Forward Only (so you can't rewind it).

You can try wrapping it with a ResultSet:

```
$results    = $statement->execute(); // generate your results

$resultSet = new ResultSet; // Zend\Db\ResultSet
$resultSet->initialize($results);

// You should now be able to iterate over this multiple times..
foreach($resultSet as $row) {
    // .. 
}

// You can now buffer if you need..
$resultSet->buffer();
// Or get an array of all items
$arrayOfResults = $resultSet->toArray();
```

Comment: This solution seems better to me because you keep wrapping the ResultSet in a ZF2 object to manipulate with. @drbeza approach should be considered in a toArray() method if that was ZF2 team intention